# Навигация в приложении(со сложной иерархией) на jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-jetpack-compose

интересует вопрос касательно навигации многомодульного и много-экранного приложения с помощью jetpack compose, может есть у кого какие наработки, статьи или библиотеки. Гугл даёт «интересный подход». Просмотрел voyager, decompose, modo. Они показались больше под мульти-платформу. Был бы очень признателен за помощь.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Не смотря на то, что библиотека Decompose - мультиплатформенная, она не только про мультиплатформу. Основное предназначение Decompose как раз заключается в разделении проекта на фичи и навигации между ними. Jetpack Compose поддерживается. Можно использовать и в обычных Андроид-проектах.